# Share database connection strings between two console applications

Tags: c#, database-connection, connection-string

**Background Information**

Currently I have two C# console applications: `Job.JobManager` and `Job.JobResources`. `Job.JobResources` stores all of the database connection strings and actual implementation for various batch jobs that I will need to run. `Job.JobManager` accepts run time arguments that calls the necessary job based on whatever was passed in.

For example: User passes in "Job4312" into `Job.JobManager` -> the method `JobDB.Job4312` is executed in `Job.JobResources`.

*I will be adding other projects later that will use the same functions in Job.JobResources*

**The Problem**

Currently I'm running into the problem where I'm forced to place the database connection strings in the `app.config` files for BOTH projects. My ideal situation would be to only have to place the connection strings in the `Job.JobResources` project. However, when I do that, I receive an exception *(thrown when the connection is trying to be established in `Job.JobResources`)* saying that the connection strings is not able to be found.

Comment: I would say put them in one table/file and get the information from there so the code is not hardcoded into every application.

Comment: @CalvinSmith I'm not trying to hardcode them in every application. My goal is to only have to place the connection strings in Job.JobResources and have the various other console applications use those values.

Comment: If your using two different applications and planning on adding more it would be repetitive adding a class or changing a value then having to rebuild every reference.

Comment: @CalvinSmith I don't think that it would be. To me, It seems pointless to have to have the connection strings in the app.config file of ever project that is going to be connecting to the database. This way, all my connection strings are going to be stored in Job.JobResources. This way, all I simply have to do is reference Job.JobResources when I create a new console application, and all of my classes are there.

Comment: I understand your point. The solution I used when configuring database connection strings was putting them into a table and referencing what i needed. Have you created the object before you try referencing the connection string or is it a constant?